# $stmt->execute() with INSERT INTO is inserting the same repeat value when in a loop

Tags: php, mysql

I'm inserting data into a MySQL Table using a for loop in PHP. I'm generating a random ID for `$botid` and then inserting it based on the amount of `$botsToAdd`.

The loop itself works but the `$botid` is always inserted with the same value. So on the first iteration of the for loop if it generated an ID of `2147483647` then all subsequent inserts are inserting with `2147483647` instead of the new `$botid`.

My code:

```
if ($botsToAdd > 0) {

    //Disable autocommit
    mysqli_autocommit($con, FALSE);

    //For loop for $botsToAdd
    for ($i = 0; $i < $botsToAdd; $i++) {
        //Generate a unique bot ID (integer) that is 11 digits long
        $botid = rand(10000000000, 99999999999);

        //Insert the bot into the cube_checkin table
        $stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO cube_checkin (cube_id, user_id, is_bot) VALUES (?, ?, 1)');
        $stmt->bind_param('ii', $cubeid, $botid);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }

    //Commit the transaction
    if (mysqli_commit($con)) {
        http_response_code(200);
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode(array("success" => "Bots have been added to the cube!"));
        exit();
    } else {
        http_response_code(400);
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode(array("error" => "There has beeen an error adding bots to the cube."));
        exit();
    }

}
```

I really cannot understand why it's behaving like this as I am closing the statement within the loop.

Comment: Is it always `2147483647` on the first iteration? What type of column is `user_id`?

Comment: I was going to say no, that was just an example but upon checking, yes. For some reason it's always `2147483647`. `user_id` is `int(11)`

Comment: `2147483647` isn't even any of the values that are being generated. I'm assuming I am hitting a limit of sorts and 2147483647 is being given as the max value?

Comment: I suggest you run https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getrandmax.php

Comment: As per @Simon Goater, running `getrandmax()` in PHP gives me `2147483647` which explains exactly why it was trying to insert with that ID. I wouldn't have ever even considered that!

Comment: You could maybe try 10000000000 + ((rand() + (1+getrandmax())*rand()) % 90000000000) instead.